# Rename flags in outlook 2003

Tags: outlook, outlook-2003

I'm using outlook 2003 and using flags to define different followup categories. However in-build 'Red Flag', 'Blue Flag' labels are not useful, I need to define custom labels. To do that, I went through [following link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/outlook-help/name-your-colored-quick-flags-HA001116845.aspx)

I successfully completed first 3 steps. While on step 4, when I right click a flag in new toolbar, I get default menu so select toolbars.

[image: Screenshot when I right click on new flags toolbar]

Has someone any idea about this problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you right-clicking the Flag icon? It looks like you right-clicked the toolbar item itself.
Sometimes, it difficult to tell. The screenshot looks like a list of your available toolbars.

This is not the context menu for the icon.

Comment: Hey sorry for late work. Yes I'm sure I clicked on flag icon. Another reason for being sure, I right clicked it at least 30-40 times, only to get same menu. You are correct that menu should appear when we click outside. For me, I'm getting same menu, no matter I right click on toolbar or any command within toolbar.